Find the sum of A, B, C and D
From the Intermediate Mathematics league of Eastern Massachusetts, Meet #1, October 2008:

In the equation below, what is the value of $A + B + C + D$ if $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are all positive integers?
$$
\dfrac{1}{A + \dfrac{1}{B + \dfrac{1}{C + \dfrac{2}{D}}}} = \dfrac{13}{70}
$$

I saw this question while a friend and I were looking through some old math league practice packets, and thought I'd post this one here.
(Sorry for the skewed MathJax, I tried my best but I just couldn't get things looking quite right. Feel free to edit the post if you know how to fix it :) )

as much as it delighted me to see a problem from my old math team league (a bit before my time, however), I've voted to close this as it is, in fact, just a math problem

@juicifer I would personally argue that there is some amount of logical reasoning required to solve it, which is my reasoning for posting here, as opposed to a different SE site or not posting altogether.

Mathematical answer here. This is called a continued fraction. Every rational number has a finite continued fraction. Here is a way to construct such a fraction.

 First, invert the fraction
 $$\frac{13}{70} =\frac{1}{\dfrac{70}{13}}$$
 Then separate the integer part of the fraction
 $$\frac{13}{70} = \frac{1}{\dfrac{70}{13}} =\frac{1}{\dfrac{65+5}{13}} = \dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{5}{13}}$$
 Repeat the same process with the remaining fraction
 $$\begin{align}\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{5}{13}} &=\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{13}{5}}}\\&=\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{3}{5}}}\\&=\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{5}{3}}}}\\&=\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{2}{3}}}}\end{align}$$
 Then
 $$\frac{13}{70}= \dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{2}{3}}}}$$
 and $$A+B+C+D = 5 + 2+ 1+ 3 = 11$$

